# Cannot define shared resource with custom values in TeamCity 10.0.2

Tags: teamcity

There are 3 options available for shared resource type:

- Infinite resource
- Resource with quota
- Resource with custom values

I select Resource with custom values, define them in Custom values field and then save the settings. However, when I open this resource for edit, I see that the resource type went back to "Infinite resource" value.

Is this a bug or feature and does that affect functionality?

Comment: Have you checked the teamcity-server.log?

Comment: I've no idea what in the log to look for

Comment: Any exceptions (stack traces) around the time when you tried to save this?